# Azure search unable to find location & highlighting of text in the PDF file

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am working on Azure search with 2 PDF files which contains images and text, I am able to execute the search results properly, However i am unable to highlight the text which is in image. 
In a short i am not able to minimize my search to extract only the searched content.

I am using post man to get the results

Example:

- When i call

https://XXXXXXXX.search.windows.net/indexes/azureblob-index/docs?api-version=2019-05-06&search=microsoft%20center

I gives me whole JSON with many text without exact highlighter

NOTE: i have enables OCR also in the indexer

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `highlight=[string]` parameter in your request.
See the [Search Documents documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#request) for details.

If that doesn't help, can you explain more about your expected results?